# How to check if DIV element is disabled using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

htmlcode:

```
div id="divUndo" runat="server"
```

I am disabling divUndo in the code-behind under certain conditions using the below statement.
VB.NET:

```
divUndo.disabled=true
```

How can I check if the "`divUndo`" is disabled or not using jquery?

Comment: jQuery, and JavaScript in general, works on the HTML in the client. What does your HTML look like (view source)?

Comment: What does a "disabled" `div` look like in HTML? It's not a concept I'm familiar with.

Comment: How does the code-behind return the div when it is disabled? does it get a disabled attribute?

Comment: The disabled attribute is meant for form input elements, not divs.

Comment: This is a tricky question. `<div>` elements do not support the `disabled` attribute, but if you run the code in your question, I think on most browsers `$("#divUndo").prop("disabled")` will be `true` but `$("#divUndo").attr("disabled")` will be `undefined`.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, actually it's the opposite, `prop('disabled')` returns `undefined`

Comment: @Maksim, interesting, `prop("disabled")` actually returns `true` and `attr("disabled")` returns `"disabled"` on my (hopelessly outdated, I know) Firefox 8. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zJLkZ/) for testing purposes.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, there's something more interesting, I tested it a different way http://jsfiddle.net/96LRu/ But I have the same result as you have when I use your example in the latest Chrome(beta). My example is more realistic though, because server side code disables `div` before html sent to the client.

Comment: @Maksim, that's indeed interesting, as you're using the valueless form of the `disabled` attribute. My guts tell me it makes sense for `prop()` to return `undefined` in that case (as the attribute *has no defined value*), but I don't know if that behavior conforms to the spec or not.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, i think using valueless attribute is a correct way to use `disabled` attribute in HTML5, but in this case it doesn't matter. Here's an updated example http://jsfiddle.net/96LRu/1/ (which is more correct actually, since asp.net will render it as `disabled="disabled"`)

Comment: @Maksim, you're perfectly right, then again your `disabled` attribute is still present in the markup instead of being added by an assignment to a DOM property as in the questioner's code. `prop()` and `attr()` rely on these very semantics. That's what I was trying to say to AlfalfaStrange in my comment to his answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12320/discussion-between-maksim-vi-and-frederic-hamidi)

Answer (score 8):

ASP.NET allows you to set `Disabled` attribute on any HtmlControl object. And in your example it renders as

`<div id="divUndo" disabled="disabled"><div>`

and in javascript can be checked like

```
$('#divUndo').attr('disabled') !== undefined
```

But according to W3C

> The following elements support the disabled attribute: BUTTON, INPUT,
>   OPTGROUP, OPTION, SELECT, and TEXTAREA.

Therefore it may not work or work differently in different browsers. You shouldn't rely on using `disabled` attribute on `div` in your javascript or css.

Answer (score 3):

In standard ASP.Net Webforms, when you set the [disabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.disabled.aspx) property to true it renders like:

```
<div id="MainContent_divundo" disabled="disabled">This is Undo!</div>
```

You can probably use the the standard jQuery [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to read the value.  Most likely [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) will not work ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSHW7/)).

```
if ($("#MainContent_divundo").attr("disabled") == "disabled")
{
}
```

I don't know why you'd want to do this, so this is most likely a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable a div in any way that JavaScript (or HTML, for that matter) would recognize.  It may be a weird .net attribute of some sort, but not something the client side would recognize.

If you can explain what your ultimate goal is, we could perhaps assist you with some alternatives.

Comment: it adds `disabled="disabled"` to a div element, doesn't look like a weird .net attribute to me.

Comment: @Maksim Vi but that doesn't mean anything. The browser won't do anything with that attribute on a div tag.

Comment: I said "You can't disable a div". While you are correct that one can stick that attribute there, it doesn't do anything on the client side. It may do something on the .net side.

Comment: sorry, but you said JavaScript would not recognize `disabled` attribute on div, that is not correct. It's still a correct attribute, but on an element that doesn't support it.

Comment: We're nitpicking semantics here. But it's Friday. And I'm bored. ;) I suppose JS could recognize the attribute, just as you could have it read any attribute. I'm saying a div having that attribute does NOT make it disabled. You could write your own JS to do something with that information, I suppose. But that's a different topic.

Comment: Oh yes it kind of makes it disabled. In latest browsers you can even style it. http://jsfiddle.net/vxaB4/ I know what you mean, but your original statement is incorrect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12321/discussion-between-maksim-vi-and-da)

Comment: "it kind of makes it disabled" = does it? What does it do? I'll have to play with it a bit.