# Check if a div is disabled jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check whether `myDiv1` is disabled. If so, I need to hide `myDiv2`, otherwise I need to show `myDiv2`.

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isDisabled = $('#myDiv1').is('[disabled=disabled]')
    alert(isDisabled); //this always returns false
    if(isDisabled)
        $("#myDiv2").hide();
    else
        $("#myDiv2").show()
});
```

But `isDisabled` return  always `false` even when `myDiv1` is enabled. What am I missing here?

Comment: How does the `<div>` actually look like in the DOM?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if DIV element is disabled using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955571/how-to-check-if-div-element-is-disabled-using-jquery)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

So many answers, but none addressing the actual problem: A [`div` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) doesn't allow an attribute of type `disabled`. On a `div` only [global attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes) are allowed, whereas `disabled` is allowed on [form elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html).

You can easily verify it by testing this HTML:

```
<div id="a" disabled></div>
<input id="b" disabled>
```

against this JavaScript:

```
var e = $('#a');
alert(e.is(':disabled'));

var e = $('#b');
alert(e.is(':disabled'));
```

Which will return `false` and `true`.

**What's a solution then?**

If you want to have an attribute that is actually named `disabled` use a `data-*` attribute:

```
<div id="c" data-disabled="true"></div>
```

And check it using this JavaScript:

```
var e = $('#c');
alert(e.data('disabled'));
```

or:

```
var e = $('#c');
alert('true' === e.attr('data-disabled'));
```

Depending on how you're going to handle attached `data-*`-attributes. Here you can read more about jQuery's [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) which is used in the first example.

**Demo:**

[Try before buy](https://jsfiddle.net/o0xwpr35/)

Comment: Good point regarding `disabled` property/attribute on non input element but just beware that jq `$.fn.data` isn't mapped to `data-*` attribute once parsed. OP could wish to change the attribute value later (not the dataset property). The correct answer in this case would be to use `$.fn.attr()` method: `var isDisabled = $('#c').attr('data-disabled') === "true";` in jQuery or the dataset property of DOM node: `document.querySelector('#c').dataset.disabled`.

Comment: @A.Wolff True that. While writing I was thinking, how much should I go into detail about different ways one can handle data and data-attributes attached to a DOM element. I've updated the answer to reflect the second approach from your comment as well.

Answer (score 7):

The reason why **`isDisabled`** returns **`false`** to you is, because you have most likely set the following in your HTML:

```
<div id = "myDiv1" disabled>...</div>
```

In reality, **`disabled`** means **`disabled = ""`**, so, since **`"disabled" != ""`**, if you keep using **`$('#myDiv1').is('[disabled=disabled]')`** you will always  get **`false`**.

**What will work:**

To make this work, as other answers have mentioned, you can use:

1. **`$('#myDiv1').attr('disabled') == "disabled"`** *([@guradio answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41736166/6313073))*,
2. **`$('#myDiv1').is('[disabled=""]')`** or
3. **`$('#myDiv1')[0].getAttribute("disabled") != null`**.

**What won't work:**

1. While **`$('#myDiv1')[0].getAttribute("disabled") != null`** will work regardless of what element the attribute is set on, on the other hand, **`$('#myDiv1')[0].disabled`** will only work on 'form elements' and will return **`undefined`** for all others *(check out the note at the end)*.
2. The same occurs when you use **`$('#myDiv1').is(':disabled')`** as well.

---

Alternatively, if you want to keep your code intact, you can set **`disabled = "disabled"`** in your HTML and the problem will be solved.

---

**Working Example *(using 2.)*:**

```js
/* --- JavaScript --- */
$(document).ready(function(isDisabled) {
  isDisabled = $('#myDiv1').is('[disabled=""]');
  if (isDisabled) $("#myDiv2").hide();
  else $("#myDiv2").show()
  
  /* Will return 'true', because disabled = "" according to the HTML. */
  alert(isDisabled);
});
```

```html
<!--- HTML --->
<script src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "myDiv1" disabled>DIV 1</div>
<div id = "myDiv2">DIV 2</div>
```

---

**Note:** Beware, however, that the **`disabled`** attribute is meant to be used with 'form elements' rather than anything else, so be sure to check out the very informative answer of [@insertusernamehere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41736549/6313073) for more on this. Indicatively, the **`disabled`** attribute is meant to be used with the following elements:

1. **`button`**,
2. **`fieldset`** *(not supported by IE)*,
3. **`input`**,
4. **`keygen`** *(not supported by IE)*,
5. **`optgroup`** *(supported by IE8+)*,
6. **`option`** *(supported by IE8+)*,
7. **`select`** and
8. **`textarea`**.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($('#myDiv1').is(':disabled'))
       $("#myDiv2").hide();
    else
      $("#myDiv2").show()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isDisabled = $('#myDiv1').is(':disabled')
    if(isDisabled)
       $("#myDiv2").hide();
    else
      $("#myDiv2").show()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set disabled property for your div

```
<div id="myDiv" disabled="disabled">This is Div</div>
```

Then you need to use this

```
 $('#myDiv1').is('[disabled=disabled]')
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#myDiv1').attr('disabled') == "disabled" ? $("#myDiv2").hide() : $("#myDiv2").show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv1' disabled="true">1</div>
<div id='myDiv2'>2</div>
```

Try this way. But i dont think div has disable attribute or property

```js
$('#myDiv1[disabled=true]').length > 0 ? $("#myDiv2").hide() : $("#myDiv2").show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv1' disabled="true">1</div>
<div id='myDiv2'>2</div>
```

Using attribute selector

[attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

> Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("#div1").prop("disabled")` to check whether the div is disabled or not. Here is a sample snippet to implement that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .container {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: grey;
            margin: 5px;
            float: left;
        }
        div {
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ChkBox" onclick="UpdaieDivStatus()" /> Toggle access
    </div>
    <div id="div1" class="container">Div 1</div>
    <div id="div2" class="container">Div 2</div>


    <script>
        function UpdaieDivStatus() {
            if ($("#ChkBox").prop('checked')) {
                $("#div1").prop("disabled", true);
            } else {
                $("#div1").prop("disabled", false);
            }
            if ($('#div1').prop('disabled')) {
                $("#div2").hide();
            } else {
                $("#div2").show();
            }
            console.log($("#div1").prop("disabled"));
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at this [MDN HTML attribute reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes), you will note that the `disabled` attribute should only be used on the following tags:

> button, command, fieldset, input, keygen, optgroup, option, select,
>   textarea

You can choose to create your own HTML `data-*` attribute (or even drop the data-) and give it values that would denote the element being disabled or not. I would recommend differentiating the name slightly so we know its a custom created attribute.

[How to use data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

For example:

```
$('#myDiv1').attr('data-disabled') == "disabled"
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `disabled` attribute on any HtmlControl object. In your example it renders as:

```
<div id="myDiv1" disabled="disabled"><div>
<div id="myDiv2" ><div>
```

and in javascript can be checked like

```
('#myDiv2').attr('disabled') !== undefined
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
      if($('#myDiv1').attr('disabled') !== undefined)
        $("#myDiv2").hide();
    else
      $("#myDiv2").show()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv1" disabled="disabled">Div1<div>
  <div id="myDiv2" >Div1<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use CSS?

html:

`<div id="isMyDiv" disabled>This is Div</div>`

css:

```
#isMyDiv {
    /* your awesome styles */
}
#isMyDiv[disabled] {
    display: none
}
```